# How to reuse search result in Leaflet.Control.Search?

Tags: angular, leaflet

I'm coding a map application, that uses Leaflet.Control.Search with Nominatim geocoder.

My goal is a functionality, that will trigger after finding a place, which shows a pop-up, which allows user to generate report.

This is my map-canvas.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.map = L.map('lmap').setView([51.91, 19.14], 7);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);


      this.map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
      url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
      jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
      propertyName: 'display_name',
      propertyLoc: ['lat', 'lon'],
      marker: L.circleMarker([0, 0], { radius: 30 }),
      autoCollapse: true,
      autoType: false,
      minLength: 2
    }));

    this.mapLoaded.emit({ map: this.map, L: L });
  }
```

EDIT:

Changed my question to be more matching with title.

Answer (score 0):

For that matter s`earch:locationfound` event could be utilized which

> fired after moved and show markerLocation

and popup instantiated like this:

```
controlSearch.on("search:locationfound", function(e) {
  const popup = L.popup({})
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("Some content goes here...")
    .openOn(map);
});
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrnmxh)